# What books will help me learn everything I can about SSL/PKI?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, encryption, tls, pki

Since SSL is the backbone of the internet, (now technically called TLS), what are some good books I should read up on to understand all aspects of it.

I suppose I'll need to learn some math, some PKI books, crypto, and Sysadmin books as well.  Since that isn't a complete list I'm interested in hearing what you think is wise to learn as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this isn't taken as spam, but since you specifically asked about books on SSL/TLS - my recent book, ["Implementing SSL/TLS using cryptography and PKI"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470920416)  is targeted specifically at programmers with no specific background in crypto math or PKI who want a complete understanding of SSL/TLS, including cryptography and certificates.  The first half covers the cryptography algorithms that TLS relies on, and the second half describes the protocol and its implementation in detail.

There are only a handful of other books on SSL - Eric Rescorla's is probably the best, but fairly out-of-date, and Rolf Oppliger's is good (and much more recent), but both are higher level, and assume that the reader has a strong background in cryptography and PKI.

Answer (score 5):

wikipedia

there are excellent pages on [SSL/TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) and most other [crypto topics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Cryptography). as the tech changes, these pages will change with them.

Answer (score 1):

I have always liked Kaufman, Perlman, Speciner's book [Network Security](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130460192). It contains quite a bit more than just SSL/TLS but the sections there on SSL and PKI are really quite good.